# rails form with validation always failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm stuck on this... Asked a few questions already, but can't get my head around this.

I have a form for adding bibliography (model `Biblio`) that has a simple validation field on `title` of the bibliography.

Validation always fails, even when valid data is added.

MODEL

```
class Biblio < ApplicationRecord

    # validates_presence_of :auteurs => there's a nested form too but
    # I commented it out in order to isolate the problem

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :auteurs
    validates :titre, presence: true
```

CONTROLLER

(full text and I didn't translate in order to avoid typos)

```
def new
    @biblio = Biblio.new(params_biblio)
    @biblio.auteurs.build
end

def nouveau 
# this method renders 'nouveau.html.erb', 
# that contains the form allowing the addition of bibliography
    @biblio = Biblio.new

    if params[:id] # id is an optional parameter
        @auteur = Auteur.find(params[:id])
        @idauteur = @auteur.id
    end
  end

def ajouter
# is the method that treats the post form that was sent

    @biblio = Biblio.new
    if @biblio.save
        # the 4 following lines are irrelevant here as they only add the 
        # second and subsequent authors to the join table. 
        # No validation and works fine.
        b = auteurs_devises(params[:biblio][:auteurs])
        aut = b.map do |var|
            lett = Auteur.find(var) 
            lett.biblios << @biblio
        end
        redirect_to voir_biblio_url(Biblio.last)
     else
       if params[:id]
           @auteur = Auteur.find(params[:id])
           @idauteur = @auteur.id
       end
       render 'nouveau'
     end
 end
```

THE VIEW:

```
<%= form_for :biblio, url: administration_ajoute_biblio_url do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :auteurs do |aut| %>
    <%= aut.label t('auteur') %>
    <%= aut.text_field :nom , :name =>"biblio[auteurs][nom]", data: {autocomplete_source: auteurs_enum_path} %>
<% end %>

<%= f.label t('titre').capitalize  %>
    <%= f.text_field :titre %>
```

These are the params that are sent to the method `nouveau`:

```
Started POST "/administration/biblios/nouveau" for ::1 at 2017-02-07 21:28:28 +0100
Processing by Administration::BibliosController#ajouter as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+354h4M0Tg+BX21XAuQ6YMKS0BGQ8UjET8paKjkGCBsS1up1lB131KsoaCy563X4juDz0EJy46WgXbHcu51Kgw==", "biblio"=>{"auteurs"=>{"nom"=>"Godding"}, "titre"=>"Test Tuesday Evening", "soustitre"=>"", "recueil"=>"", "editeur"=>"", "annee"=>"", "isbn"=>"", "genre"=>"source", "revue_id"=>"", "revue_no"=>"", "revue_page"=>"", "lieu"=>"", "commentaire"=>""}, "commit"=>"Enregistrer"}
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering administration/biblios/nouveau.html.erb within layouts/messources
```

CONTROLLER AGAIN

```
def params_biblio
params.require(:biblio).permit(
                        :titre, 
                        :soustitre, 
                        :editeur, 
                        :isbn, 
                        :recueil, 
                        :genre, 
                        :revue_id, 
                        :revue_no, 
                        :revue_page, 
                        :annee, 
                        :lieu, 
                        :commentaire,
                        auteurs: [:nom] )
end
```

For the sake of completeness, here's my routes.rb:

```
# ADMINISTRATION => BIBLIOGRAPHIE
get 'biblios/nouveau(/:id)' => 'biblios#nouveau', as: 'nouvelle_biblio'  
post 'biblios/nouveau(/:id)' => 'biblios#ajouter', as: 'ajoute_biblio'
delete 'biblios/supprime/:id' => 'biblios#supprime', as: 'supprime_biblio'
get 'biblios/maj/:id' => 'biblios#cherche_maj', as: 'maj_biblio'
patch 'biblios/maj/:id' => 'biblios#maj', as: 'patch_maj_biblio'
```

I must be blind. I'm doing something wrong... I put a title to this bibliography ('Test Tuesday Evening'), this is the only field on which I left a validation, and despite this, validation always fails.

Comment: Replace `@biblio.save` with `@biblio.save!` - the bang will throw an exception and you'll see the validation error.

Comment: Either that or set a breakpoint with byebug and step into the controller.